# Can't create a page for testing

Tags: unit-test, controller

I'm trying to create a page in my test class like this:

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.testPage;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Compilation error: Page testPage does not exist.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: May be the page really doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.

Comment: A PageReference, as the name suggests is a reference to an existing page.  It doesn't create pages.

Comment: I thought in order to test a controller I need to create a page in apex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Page.**testPage**" 
The highlighted text should always be name of valid VF page. We use this as a reference while covering the corresponding controller class. VF page cannot be created in context of Test Class.

Answer (score 2):

To test a controller, for the most part, you never need to call `Test.setCurrentPage` at all. In fact I have never needed to do so, because even when I am parsing parameters from `ApexPages.currentPage`, I do not actually care what its URL is. It's a fairly esoteric function.